# What is the recommended way for me to use git in my Lithium project?

Tags: php, git, lithium

After searching through many PHP frameworks to figure out which to learn and use, I've tentatively settled on Lithium. It looks great. Except, I'm not entirely sure how to best manage the Lithium apps I write in git, because of the recommended way of getting the code. The manual [suggests](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/getting-started/installation.wiki):

```
git clone git://github.com/UnionOfRAD/framework.git my_app
cd my_app
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

This results in a non-empty main repository (2000+ commits in the history at present). Should I simply be committing my own changes within this same repository (in my own branches?) and pulling/merging when there are changes, or is there some other way that's recommended?

I know that I can also just download the files without cloning the repository, but since the manual indicates this is recommended I figured there must be a good reason and an ideal way of doing it. (I presume it makes it easier to update the framework when a new version comes out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your preferred setup.
If I want to quickly get rolling then a checkout of the example app works great. It has a bootstap config, example controllers and some views. But once you transcend that I suggest creating your own baseline app-repo and deploying the framework itself pr server and not pr app.
The *app/config/bootstrap/libraries.php* can easily be changed to load lithium itself from elsewhere.

So

1. Deploy lithium pr server (/home/lithium is my preference)
2. Create your own baseline app by copying the default li3 one and stripping/modifying it
3. Create a flexible vhost configuration so you can just *git clone base-app ~/sites/foo-app*, or similar, for quickly get rolling with a new app.

I have my (out-of-date by now) baseline app [on github](https://github.com/nervetattoo/li3_start)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In git you get a copy of all the history. You can track your work in your own branch and synchronize as you see fit using pull or fetch.

Since you are using github, fork that repo and clone from the fork. Should you want to contribute, you can create pull requests.

EDIT:

Initially, all you need to do is clone:

```
git clone <url to the repo>
git submodule --init --recursive
```

If you are not contributing, then the workflow is easy from then on:

```
git fetch
```

to fetch the latest from github

```
git merge --ff-only origin/master
git submodule update --recursive
```

If you get errors because you changed a file by accident, you can

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git clean -xdf
```

and start with the merge step again. You may need to go into the submodule directories and do the above 2 steps there if the changes happened there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This question has more to do with working with this particular repository and its submodules. If I understand the manual correctly he should be committing directly to this repo and can reconfigure the remotes if he wants to push his commits to a remote repository.

Comment: Indeed, my question is with regards to using the lithium framework to develop my own web apps, not contributing to the lithium project. Since, when cloning the repository using the exact sequence of commands given in the lithium manual, I end up with the full commit history of the lithium project itself, I'm wondering if that's correct and I should just do all my work in the same repo or if there's some specific thing I'm supposed to do for my own work that is recommended by lithium users/developers and which the manual leaves out.

Comment: Added some more explanation. Hope it makes sense now.